When to use __must_hold() with RCU macros?
If a function in the Linux kernel calls the rcu_dereference() macro to dereference a shared pointer without first calling rcu_read_lock() to enter an RCU read-side critical section, is it correct and preferable to annotate the function with the __must_hold() macro?
For example, the function radix_tree_deref_slot() calls rcu_dereference(), but is not annotated with __must_hold(slot):
static inline void *radix_tree_deref_slot(void __rcu **slot)
{
    return rcu_dereference(*slot);
}

The documentation for radix_tree_deref_slot() states that it must be called "within rcu_read_lock() regions" (i.e., RCU read-side critical sections); however, the function's signature does not indicate this requirement. The kernel's static analyzer sparse offers the __must_hold() macro to make this requirement explicit (and enables sparse to do some lock checking I believe), but is not used here. Is there a reason for this, or was this decision likely made arbitrarily? I don't see a reason not to use __must_hold() here, but fear I am missing something since several functions in the kernel follow this trend of calling rcu_dereference() outside of a critical section, without a __must_hold() annotation.
